# Will Sims 3 Windows-only DVD serial work on Mac?

Tags: macos, the-sims-3

I have one of the early Sims 3 DVD versions that apparently did not come with a Mac installer.  If I could get ahold of a Mac DVD for installation, would it be possible to use my Windows CD-key?  Or do I need to buy an entirely new copy to play on my Mac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be my own bad... I had mistakenly remembered my DVD as being PC only, when in fact it was my Sims 2 DVD that had no Mac installer.  So basically, yes, the serial works considering it's a PC/Mac combined DVD :)

Answer (score 0):

Och, it's been a while. From what I remember, the CD-Key is only used to associate your EA games account with your Sims purchase, and thereafter merely does a CD-check when you want to run the game. So in theory, it should be possible.

Of course, if you already have the ability to get a hold of a Mac DVD, there's nothing wrong with trying it!